# Should "xy problem" questions be updated so the question is in line with the accepted solution?

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

I've seen questions that are handled and resolved as "xy problems". Let's say it's a more subtle case, giving a specific answer to a generic question. The answer gets accepted, while the actual question in the title is not answered. Later duplicates are closed based on this question, which does not provide an actual answer. Searches lead to this question with unhelpful answers.

Comment: Such questions are unclear. fix them or close them.

Comment: What stops you to provide answer that answer the actual question and collect all reputation coming from duplicates? Accepted answer is just post that helper OP - no requirement to answer the question or be even remotely correct/good answer... Unless you are talking about true XY-problems that can't be really answered (editing question to match answer may be an option, but if it is becoming duplicate target maybe it's not XY-problem in itself)

Comment: And are you sure the new questions that get closed as dupe of this one aren't themselves XY-problems?